# Python Pip Install For Specific Version

Tags: python, pip, installation

how do I go about installing for python2.7 version only?
Right now when I  run this : python -m pip install requests tweepy python-bittrex
It's only for python 3

I'd like to install for python 2

(I have both versions installed)

THanks

Comment: please, check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/101634/663767) to get python 2.7

Comment: What you're looking for is virtualenv, google "virtualenv python versions", you might also be interested in anaconda

Comment: thanks, solved it by going cd to the directory and then running

Answer (score 0):

There might be a conflict with environment variables.

Try this

> python2.7 -m pip install

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but it's giving me error :
'python2.7' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I've added the path

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: You have to add both folders to the environment variables (python folder, python/Scripts folder)

Comment: 'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I added these two paths: 
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts

in user variables environment paths
do i have to remove the path for python3? Thank you

Comment: Try then. Remember that every change of environment variables needs you to restart cmd

Comment: Removed paths for 3.6 and restarted cmd with admiin priv, still the same error.

Comment: Oh god, what's happening? My last idea is to uninstall python2.7 and install it again. Be careful and check the checkbox "Add to PATH" in the Python installer

Comment: There is no option to add to path sadly. I thank you very much for all the help. I figured out a way. I cd to c:\ first and then run the install 
it works this way apparently

Comment: Yes, that's the longer way how to deal with that. No problem.